# SafeScriptManager From Where Can I download Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I read many articles like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647244.aspx

But no where i can't find a **Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll**

I only find Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll

I added to the reference

But there isn't:

```
<spg:SafeScriptManager ID="SafeScriptManager" runat="server" />
```

It's togled me by the green as is no lated.

Answer (score 1):

The SPG tool set is a codeplex download.

http://spg.codeplex.com/

It is not included in OOTB SharePoint installs.

Comment: Yes I saw this to, but how to instal this on project. Where It is. I don't understand last of sentence.

Comment: Where Can Found a Reference. its a Control Library or dll How find this ?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used it. OOTB = Out Of The Box = Vanilla SharePoint.

Comment: Abd You never used ScriptManager and Update Panel in Sharepoint ?

Comment: `<asp:ScriptManager />` is used by SP OOTB and is not the same as `<spg:SafeScriptManager />`. You don't need the SPG versions.

Comment: But when I add a `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />` to webpart compilator telling a Script Manager are duplicated.

Comment: You can only have one `ScriptManager` on the page. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35804/using-ajaxcontroltoolkit-in-sharepoint-multiple-instances-of-scriptmanagers/35809#35809 If you have additional questions please post them as new questions.

Comment: Unfortunately http://spg.codeplex.com/releases deoesn't contain Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll at all. Where else can I find the library?